# A solution to $a_x(b-c)_y+b_x(c-a)_y+c_x(a-b)_y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, partial-derivative

Let $a,b,c \in k[x,y]$, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
Further assume that each monomial in each of $\{a,b,c\}$ has odd degree.
I wish to find a solution to:
$a_x(b-c)_y+b_x(c-a)_y+c_x(a-b)_y=0$,
where $_x$ denotes the partial derivative with respect to $x$ and $_y$ denotes the partial derivative with respect to $y$.

The only solution I have found is $a=b=c$.
Is it the unique solution to that equation?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about
\begin{align*}
a &= y + x\\[4pt]
b &= y - x\\[4pt]
c &= y\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
?

Comment: You are right..this is also a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Can you clearly specify what function is known and what is unknown.

If the three functions $a(x,y),b(x,y),c(x,y)$ are all unknown, chose arbitrary functions for $b(x,y)$ and $c(x,y)$ which then become known and you get a PDE to be solved for $a(x,y)$.

So, they are an infinity of solutions. A lot are easy to find.

For example, if we arbitrary chose $\begin{cases} b(x,y)=x+y \\c(x,y)=xy\end{cases}$

the PDE is $(1-x)a_x+(y-1)a_y=y-x$ which solution from method of characteristics is $a(x,y)=x+y+F\left((x-1)(y-1)\right)$. This gives a set of solutions :
$$\begin{cases} b(x,y)=x+y \\c(x,y)=xy \\
a(x,y)=x+y+F\left((x-1)(y-1)\right)\end{cases}$$
with any differentiable function $F$.

One can do the same with other choice of functions $b(x,y)$ and $c(x,y)$ leading to other solutions of the initial problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, the three functions are all unknown. Please notice that I assumed that each of $\{a,b,c\}$ has all monomials of odd degree, so your answer with $c=xy$ is not relevant.

Comment: Ho! Sorry, I didn't noticed it. So my whole answer isn't relevant. You should not accept it.

Comment: It's ok, thanks for trying to help! Any adjustments of your answer to the special case are welcome.