# How to solve $A_xB_y+A_yB_x=0$, $A,B \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, commutative-algebra, partial-derivative, jacobian

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be arbitrary polynomials of two variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$.

Assume that $A_xB_y+A_yB_x=0$,
where $\cdot _x$ is the partial derivative with respect to $x$
and $\cdot_y$ is the partial derivative with respect to $y$.

> **Question 1:** Is it possible to find a general solution to such equation?

I really apologize if this is an easy question; I am not familiar with the theory of solving such equations.

**An example:**
$A=x+y, B=x-y$.
Here $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is skew-symmetric
w.r.t. the involution $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$, but general $A$ symmetric and $B$ skew-symmetric do not work, for example $A=x^2+y^2, B=x-y$.

> **Question 2:** Replace $A_xB_y+A_yB_x=0$ by $A_xB_y-A_yB_x=0$.
> What is the answer in this case?

> **Question 3:** Let $h \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, $h$ is any polynomial in one variable $x$.
> What is the solotion to $(h-A_x)B_y+A_yB_x=0$? to $(h-A_x)B_y-A_yB_x=0$?

**Edit:**

If an answer for a general $h$ is too complicated, I do not mind to assume that $h=1$, so Question 3 becomes:
What is the solotion to $(1-A_x)B_y+A_yB_x=0$? to $(1-A_x)B_y-A_yB_x=0$?

Now let us consider
$A_xB_y-A_yB_x=-B_x$, namely,
$A_xB_y=(A_y-1)B_x$
(in qeustion 3, I have asked about
$A_xB_y-A_yB_x=B_y$, but these are analog cases).

A possible solution is:
$A=(x+y)^3+y, B=(x+y)^2$.

More generally, if I am not wrong,
$A=f(C)+y, B=g(C)$,
where $C \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[T]$.

> **Question 4:** Is it true that $A=f(C)+y, B=g(C)$ is a general solution to $A_xB_y=(A_y-1)B_x$?
> If not, is it possible to describe all additional solutions?

See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203573/a-solution-to-a-xb-c-yb-xc-a-yc-xa-b-y-0?rq=1) question.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe $A, B \in C^1(D)$, where $D$ is a topos?

Comment: @dmtri, thank you for your comment. Please, could you elaborate?

Comment: Actually no,  because I misunderstood the question... You do mean A,  B are polynomials of 2 variables with complex coefficients?  Right?

Comment: Yes. this is what I meant.

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help.

Comment: Since the equation is homogeneous, it suffices to let both $A$ and $B$  be homogeneous.

Comment: @KentaS, thank you for your hint/idea. Please, what is the answer for the homogeneous case?

Comment: It works at least when $B(x,y)=A(x,-y)$. It may be interesting to identify some other cases where it works, in order to get a feeling on what kind of solution it will get. Also something like if you have $(A,B)$ and $(C,D)$ solutions, is there a natural way to combine them into another solution ? summing won't work but maybe something different might.

Comment: @P.Quinton, thank you for sharing your ideas. Nice. So you suggest to find 'fundamental solutions' or 'a generating set (in an appropriate sense) for all solutions'? Hopefully, this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me deal with the case $A_xB_y-A_yB_x=0$. This is equivalent to the existence of a polynomial $t(x,y)$ and polynomials $P,Q$ in one variable such that $A=P(t),B=Q(t)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Interesting! Please, what about the other cases?

Comment: Yes, I understand, this is the Jacobian of $A$ and $B$, and it is a known theorem that the Jacobian of two two-variable polynomials is zero iff they are of the form you mentioned.

Comment: In the case $A_xB_y+A_yB_x$ I do not see how this may be a Jacobian of some variation of $A$ and $B$. (I thought to multiply $A$ or $B$ or both by $i$, but this does not work).

Comment: Is there a theory for "anti-Jacobian", defined to be $a-Jac(A,B)=A_xB_y+A_yB_x$? Maybe I should read carefully proofs of the theorem you applied and try to adjust them to this case.